# Loading disc node into ram node?

Tags: erlang, mnesia

Something I not get, I have two mnesia nodes. One has ram and other has disc copy.

My question is:

You do create schema once? But schema is where you enter nodes.

I confused and found not good documentation on this

Comment: I recommand you this chapter: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/mnesia#of-schemas-and-mnesia. BR.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by clarifying the concepts. A mnesia cluster consists of nodes and tables; nodes may have copies of the tables. The type of the copy, which may be `ram_copies`, `disc_copies`, and `disc_only_copies`, applies to a given table on a given node. A node may have different types of copies of different tables, and a table may have different types of copies on different nodes. A special case is a node which doesn't have disc based copies at all; it is called a ram only node.

The schema is a special table that stores information about the nodes and tables. Each node must have a copy of this table in the cluster; ram only nodes obviously have a ram copy, other nodes have a disc copy. To be precise, a node must have a disc copy of the schema to have a disc-based copy of any other table.

When you call `mnesia:create_schema`, you are creating a disc copy of a schema without tables, to be loaded by mnesia when it is started (this function refuses to work if mnesia is already started). If your cluster contains multiple disc-based nodes, the schema is created on all these nodes simultaneously, and when mnesia is started on these nodes, they automatically connect to each other (the nodes know about each other from the schema).

When mnesia cannot load the schema from disk at startup, it creates an empty one for itself in ram (or refuses to start, depending on settings). After that, you can either turn it into a ram-only node by calling `mnesia:change_config` on a disc-based node of the cluster, in which case the empty schema will be replaced and the node will be synchronized with the rest of the cluster, or you can start creating tables and adding other ram only nodes (which still have an empty schema), building a ram-only cluster.

A ram only node can be turned into a disc node by calling `mnesia:chang_table_copy_type` on the table `schema`. This way you can build a complete disc-based cluster dynamically from scratch, without creating a disc-based schema beforehand. However if you have a fixed set of disc nodes, it's much easier to statically initialize the schema on them before starting the cluster the first time.